# No value for argument 'eur' in constructor call

Tags: python, oop

work with OOP in Python, but I can't understand how to fix an error. No value for argument 'eur' in constructor call and No value for argument 'usd' in constructor call

```
    class Converter():
    def __init__(self, usd ,eur, rate):
        self.usd = usd
        self.eur = eur
        self.rate = rate
    
    def exchange_usd(self):
        price = self.usd*self.rate
        print(f"The purchase price {self.usd}$ will be {price}₽")
    
    def exchange_eur(self):
        price = self.eur*self.rate
        print(f"The purchase price {self.eur}€ will be {price}₽")

bank_user = input('Currency: ')

currency = Converter("eur", "usd", "rate")


if bank_user == "usd":
    currency = Converter(usd = int(input('How many dollars do you want to buy: ')), rate = int(input('Dollar rate: ')))
    currency.exchange_usd()

elif bank_user == "eur":
    currency = Converter(eur = int(input('How many euro do you want to buy: ')), rate = int(input('Euro rate: ')))
    currency.exchange_eur()
```

Comment: Add default values for the arguments to __init__, such as: ` def __init__(self, usd=0, eur=0, rate=1.0): `

Comment: currency = Converter("eur", "usd", "rate") doesn't make sense by itself, because it's passing strings (such as "eur"), instead of numeric values.

Comment: Where are you confused?  The error messages tell you what's wrong: you have three required arguments for `Converter`, and supplied only two of those.  If you want optional arguments, then repeat your tutorial on function arguments to recall how that's done.

Answer (score -1):

Keep on indentation, it should look like:

```
    class Converter():
        def __init__(self, usd ,eur, rate):
            self.usd = usd
            self.eur = eur
            self.rate = rate
    
        def exchange_usd(self):
            price = self.usd*self.rate
            print(f"The purchase price {self.usd}$ will be {price}₽")
    
        def exchange_eur(self):
            price = self.eur*self.rate
            print(f"The purchase price {self.eur}€ will be {price}₽")
```

And keep in mind that you didn't provide default values to arguments, so the rest of the code should not work.

Comment: the indentation is clearly just a copying error, it happens all the time when people post code here. Otherwise the script wouldn't even run.

Comment: @Barmar You should be familiar with site rules, please refresh them to yourself. The question is not clear and has syntax mistake (such as default arguments assignment), my answer clarifies that.

Comment: That's true, but this is clearly not the answer to the question. He said what error he's getting, which he wouldn't get with incorrect indentation.